# Jquery validation depends bootstrap switch

Tags: jquery-validate, bootstrap-switch

I want to use validation on a date field (seguro_resp_civil_validade). This field only needs to be validated when the bootstrap switch (seguro_resp_civil) is "ON".

I have this piece of code:

> seguro_resp_civil_validade: {
>
> > ```
> > required: {
> >     depends: function(element){
> >         return $("#seguro_resp_civil").hasClass("checked")
> >     }
> > }
> > ```
> >
> > },

This is not working, maybe because I'm using a bootstrap-switch and the 'hasClass' is not correct for this use. How can I check if the bootstrap-switch is checked?

Thanks